# Are hardware interrupts still needed on embedded devices (as opposed to flags)?

Tags: embedded, cpu, cpu-architecture, interrupt, hardware

In general, ISR for hardware interrupts on embedded devices should be very short: Usually just setting a flag which will be read under the normal course of execution (e.g. in a task loop).

This begs the question: If so, what is the purpose of fullfledged hardware interrupts which interrupt control? Why doesn't the MCU simply set a flag (in a designated register, memory mapped), which can be checked by the task loop just the same? Why go through the expense (in MCU circuitry, in execution disruption, and in complexity) of actually diverting execution if all we're going to do is set a flag?

Background: My goal here is to *understand*.  If the answer is "99% of the time, you're right, but here's 1% of the case where it makes a difference...", that will accomplish my goal.

Comment: what if you want to count number of interrupts, checking register in loop is not enough as it can be not fast enough and count 2 interrupts as one

Comment: @IłyaBursov Would you agree that's a very limited case? Aside from benchmarking or debugging, you generally want to take _action_ (e.g. read a queue), not just tally.

Comment: it is how real time clocks are implemented, so it is not even 1%, but much larger use case

Comment: Interrupts allow waking up from a sleep state, meaning you can save power instead of running in a spin loop waiting for something to do.  Also, in a more complicated system with multiple flags, your interrupts might not *just* set a flag variable, they might also queue a task to run later.  (e.g. the Linux kernel's bottom-half mechanism).  So the main code doesn't have to loop over every flag that might exist in the system.  (Or especially poll them before it finishes whatever other task it was working on, if you want any kind of pre-emption!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption "*Usually just setting a flag [...]*" is not at all 99% of the use cases, not even near.

I'm in the world of embedded software since 40+ years, and the interrupt service routines setting flags are in the minority, in my personal subjective experience.

It's a common rule to keep an interrupt service routine short-running. But this is only correct in relation to the requirements. What is "short" in the context of the target system? Some systems need run-times shorter than a few microseconds, or even less. Others can perfectly live with multiple seconds. Therefore you need to specify the requirements before you can tell how short an interrupt service routine needs to run.

The vast majority of interrupt service routines I came across or wrote do more than just setting a flag.

For example, servicing a UART commonly includes fetching the next data to send or buffering the received data. In more than one case these routines additionally preprocess the data.

In another example of my own projects, the edge-triggered interrupt service routine of an input pin decodes the [Manchester coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) data stream. It finally queues the decoded bytes. For the main thread it looks like a module providing the byte stream in its buffer.

A special, but strange example is the "operating system" of the early personal computer [ZX81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX81). Granted, this is not really an embedded system, and it is 42 years old. Anyway, it creates its video signal to view on a TV set with a mixture of non-maskable and maskable interrupts. The routine running the longest is the generation of the vertical retrace signal, it takes about 3.5ms. During this time it scans and debounces the complete keyboard matrix, among other tasks.

Next, think about exceptions. These are also hardware interrupts, detected by hardware for certain conditions, like division by zero, access violation, you name it. You will not want that they just set a flag and return to the triggering instruction.

Finally (for my answer), a preemptive multitasking system will use its interrupt service routine to switch tasks.

So, interrupts still make sense, and will keep making sense.

---

As a side note, these hardware flags you suggest already exist. Any system I used had interrupt flags that the software can poll. Actually, we built systems without using interrupt service routines just by polling (and resetting) the interrupt flags. We had our reasons.

You asked in a comment for an example for STM32. Since you did not specify further, I selected the first MCU whose [user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00443854-ultralowpower-stm32l0x0-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) I found in a quick web research: the STM32L0x0.

Chapter 21.8.8 describes the register `USART_ISR`, which includes the flag `TXE` in bit 7:

> This bit is set by hardware when the content of the USART_TDR register has been
> transferred into the shift register. It is cleared by a write to the USART_TDR register.
> The TXE flag can also be cleared by writing 1 to the TXFRQ in the USART_RQR register, in order to discard the data (only in Smartcard T=0 mode, in case of transmission failure).
> An interrupt is generated if the TXEIE bit =1 in the USART_CR1 register.

You can poll this bit in software and react accordingly. The implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @SRobertJames : By polling the flag as stated.  The flag will be set whether interrupts are enabled or not.  In an ISR you would read the flag to determine which even occurred, you can also simply poll for that flag in the normal thread context.

Comment: "nterrupt service routines setting flags are in the minority, in my personal subjective experience" Huh...? I can't really think of a MCU where there _isn't_ a corresponding flag to the interrupt. Not really set by the ISR itself but rather - the interrupt is triggered from the flag. This is at least how the whole Motorola side of things always worked, including Motorola/Freescale/NXP, Renesas, Atmel, ST... you never worked with _any_ of these parts in 40 years? I think I'm misunderstanding the answer.

Comment: @Lundin I'm afraid you misunderstood the question as well as my intro. We are talking about an ISR setting a flag, that is software, not hardware.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes more sense. And well, that's even more common, I'd say, or at least that's how I often write programs. Because I always write a HAL around a hardware timer to create a general-purpose timer with callbacks, where I can offload non-critical timer tasks that don't require hard real-time. Button/relay debouncing, communication timeouts, things like that that don't need better accuracy than rough milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

While it is probably true that if all you do is set a flag to be polled, the use of an interrupt serves no useful purpose, that is clearly not how interrupts are used, despite your false assertion to the contrary.  That would not work at all in hard real-time systems, with response times required in the order if a few microseconds.  In that case you would at least use an RTOS IPC or synchronisation mechanism to trigger a task rather than periodic polling of a flag.

Often, the needs of the hardware are such that you need to do work in the ISR to ensure it is able to correctly process further events. For example in a UART ISR you would generally read the DR and place that in a FIFO queue.  If you set a flag and wait for the main thread to handle it in its own sweet time, there is a chance that you will not read the DR in time, and cause an overrun.

In general an ISR must be both short and *deterministic*.  That is you should execute in *constant* or at least *bounded* time.  So in the above example taking from the DR and posting to a FIFO is deterministic, while whatever is receiving data from the FIFO can be far less deterministic because of the FIFO buffer.

For example assembling a packet and processing it is unlikely to be a constant time process so you would not do that in the ISR.

Essentially you need to do all the work that makes sense in an ISR, not follow some blind rule without understanding why you are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Interrupts are always the last resort. They only have one single but significant advantage and that is real-time performance. You will execute code immediately when something happens, not with the extra delay that comes from cyclically polling a flag while doing other things.

The real-time behavior of polling can only be as good as when using interrupts in the rare scenario where the MCU has *nothing* else to do but to busy-wait for an interrupt. In such scenarios one may also utilize sleep modes, which the MCU wakes up from in an interrupt-like manner, except no ISR is called, it just continues to execute from where it dozed off.

But most often, programs have better things to do than busy-wait poll, so the main concern with polling tends to be that you need to do it frequently enough not to miss the next occurrence of the flag getting set. When that happens, you have failed to meet a critical real-time deadline and from there your program design is in shambles - it has failed. It also means that you've designed in a "tight coupling" between the performance of the background program and the unrelated frequency of some hardware event. For fast recurring hardware events like ADC conversions or serial bus reception, that will typically not work out well.

Interrupts come with delay too though, the so-called *interrupt latency*. But this is often a fixed time that can either be calculated or ignored. Furthermore in case of timer interrupts where you have a counter register, it will present the time when the condition occurred/flag was set, not the time when the PC entered the ISR.

Working more or less exclusively with real-time systems, I think I've yet to write a single MCU program that didn't use at least one interrupt. At the bare minimum you'll almost always want to write a HAL around a general-purpose hardware timer, so that you can register callbacks to get executed after a certain time. And never resorting to hobbyist busy `delay()` loops, which will soon become very unwieldy as program complexity increases.

Lets say I have to simultaneously wait for a SPI bus, a LCD and a button de-bounce. Implementing that with some busy-delay scheme is just madness - use a general-purpose timer which keeps tracks of individual times and invokes callbacks when the time has passed. Button debounce/scanning can for example get completely outsourced to a cyclic timer interrupt, ideally embedded in the button driver and not cluttering down non-related parts of the program. No one else in your program need to care about how/when you debounce some buttons, that knowledge belongs to the button driver along.

All that being said, I started this post by writing that interrupts are the last resort. Because they do come with a load of problems:

- Unpredictable execution and stack depth in case of non-cyclic interrupts.
- Managing vector tables and their corresponding interrupts increases complexity and is a common source of errors. And on some MCUs it is critical to place the ISR at a certain memory location.
- The vast majority of programmers don't know how to write proper ISRs. I'm not exaggerating; some >90% of all embedded systems programmers don't know how to do this. If there is anywhere I'm dead certain to find bugs at during peer code review, then it is always in the ISRs. And well, writing a proper ISR is *difficult*. Common problems:

  - Too big/time consuming.
  - Incorrectly cleared flags.
  - Failing to `volatile` qualify shared file scope variables.
  - Failing to implement race condition protection.
  - Failing private encapsulation, exposing shared variables all over the place, aka "spaghetti/flaghetti programming".
  - Failing to consider real-time impact of the designated hardware and/or overall real-time impact.
  - Failing to benchmark maximum stack usage.
  - Maskable interrupt bugs, like drivers meddling with the global interrupt mask when they really shouldn't be doing that.
  - And so on. I'm always amazed when I have to explain fundamental stuff like how a race condition bug works, even to veteran embedded systems designers.

And because of the many problems mentioned, the use of non-cyclic interrupts is banned in safety-related software. Whereas cyclic interrupts are easier to predict in terms of real-time execution speed and peak stack memory use.

Comment: What's a "cyclic" vs. "non-cyclic" interrupt?  Is "non-cyclic" like a one-shot timer that will deliver exactly one interrupt later, not periodic?  Or since you mention stack usage, something about nesting, like an interrupt interrupt another IRQ handler?

Comment: @PeterCordes Cyclic means that it gets called on fixed, regular intervals - making it possible to calculate timing and stack usage necessary, as well as ensuring that different such interrupts do not collide needlessly. Whereas the opposite is a normal interrupt that might get called at any point in time.

Comment: @PeterCordes As for if nesting is available/allowed that's highly MCU-specific. Additionally some of the more dysfunctional ISA like PIC may have a maximum call stack depth (of 8 or so) and then an unexpected interrupt might be the culprit that unexpectedly puts the program beyond that limit.

Comment: Oh, I see, and you can just arrange their periods so two cyclic interrupts won't happen at the same time, so you can avoid nested handlers.  (e.g. relatively prime if you have more than one timer interrupt, although I assume that's rare.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah so you can treat them pretty much like processes in a RTOS, a poor man's scheduler of sorts.