# Defining an Interrupt without an ISR on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, interrupt, raspberry-pi-pico

I use the IRQ_WRAP interrupt of the PWM channels on my Raspberry Pi Pico.
However, I want to keep the latency as low as possible and avoid ISR context switches (pushing stack frame, jumping to ISR, returning from ISR) etc., so my approach is to just keep polling the pwm_hw->ints memory mapped register which tells me if the interrupt was triggered or not. (I want my User code to be synchronized to the pwm wrap so I wait for the interrupt to be triggered here)

Can I just enable the interrupt without using an ISR?
As far as I know from some googling, there is a default handler which contains a breakpoint that can be used for debugging, but without debugging it should crash your system, ChatGPT first said it is possible then changed its opinion and now also says it should not be possible.

I tried it without an ISR and it worked how I wanted it to work (although I did not check for performance differences) but now I am asking myself if this is considered normal or just a bad hack which usually is not supposed to work.

Comment: Most hardware comes in polling mode as default. That is, some status flag will get set and that's the same flag which would trigger the interrupt, should interrupts be enabled (which is optional). ChatGPT is a lie generator but it has problems keeping the lies consistent over time.

Comment: As for PWM, it is real-time critical. If you need to react after each period or duty cycle etc then you probably must use interrupts or your timing will be all over the place. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Does my answer on [Are hardware interrupts still needed on embedded devices (as opposed to flags)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144545/are-hardware-interrupts-still-needed-on-embedded-devices-as-opposed-to-flags) help you with your question? See the second part below the horizontal line: Yes, it is possible, while not common, and it is perfectly OK.

Comment: According ChatGPT: this chat bot is just good in putting words in a sequence that sound correct. Actually it has no clue about programming and abstract concepts. Use it for a quick suggestion, but only if you can distinguish nonsense from truth.